# Product title and description is not showing after replacing the public key (Base64) Android in-app purchase

Tags: android

Here is the code which I am using. I have replaced the original API key in the proper place. I have changed the Sample title and description in [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) In-app console and also replaced the public key, but in place of title and description it is showing default title of the app, not from the title I have used in In-app console.

I have attached a screen shot for better understanding. I am testing in signed [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) that already uploaded in to the Google Play. What is the problem?

The app is successfully running.

[image]

#### Code

```
public static ArrayList<VerifiedPurchase> verifyPurchase(String signedData, String signature) {
    if (signedData == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "data is null");
        return null;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "signedData: " + signedData);
    boolean verified = false;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(signature)) {
        /**
         * Compute your public key (that you got from the Android Market
         * publisher site).
         *
         * Instead of just storing the entire literal string here embedded
         * in the program, construct the key at runtime from pieces or use
         * bit manipulation (for example, XOR with some other string) to
         * hide the actual key. The key itself is not secret information,
         * but we don't want to make it easy for an adversary to replace the
         * public key with one of their own and then fake messages from the
         * server.
         *
         * Generally, encryption keys / passwords should only be kept in
         * memory long enough to perform the operation they need to perform.
         */
        String base64EncodedPublicKey = "<MY API KEY>";
        PublicKey key = BillingSecurity.generatePublicKey(base64EncodedPublicKey);
        verified = BillingSecurity.verify(key, signedData, signature);
        if (!verified) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signature does not match data.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When did you changed the item name? It can take several hours to be updated.

Comment: 2 days ago i have uploaded it. Status is now showing unpublished.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right product id inside your app.
According to your screenshot it looks like you are using

```
android.test.purchased
```

Also make sure your In-App product is published (the app itself doesn't need to be).